# Don't Forget The FIFA World Cup Event Here!

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

The FIFA World Cup is among the world's most widely viewed sporting events; almost a billion people are expected to watch the final match coming next month.

**…and they'll all have lots of questions.**

Since the World Cup will be widely searched on the Internet, you'll want to make sure Sports SE has the the best answer to those questions.

So as you watch the World Cup, whenever you have a question, **don't forget to ask them here!** You won't be the only one with that question. Millions of other people will, too. Ask them even if you think you're going to be able to find the answer yourself. Having those questions (and answers) here will help other people looking of that information. If you write detailed, ultra-clear posts with the best possible answers on the 'net, those sports fans will keep coming back for more.

#### Users Worldwide Will be Looking for a Sites Like This

This is a great opportunity to build up a body of answers about these world-wide events — questions that will be super-popular in the coming weeks as the World Cup plays out over the next month. Those questions will bring in lots of traffic from search engines. And if Sports SE continues to have great answers like we have in the past, we stand a good chance of attracting some great new users who will continue to contribute to this site for years to come.

[image]
<sup>*Photo labeled for reuse [courtesy Wikipedia.com](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_FIFA_World_Cup_Group_A)*</sup>

Comment: If the 2012 Euros were any indication, this will be a great boost to the site.

Comment: @MichaelMyers _If the shoe fits, wear it!_